# Creating Numpy Matrix from pyspark dataframe

Tags: numpy, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe `child` with columns like:

```
lat1 lon1
80    70
65    75
```

I am trying to convert it into numpy matrix using IndexedRowMatrix as below:

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import IndexedRow, IndexedRowMatrix

mat = IndexedRowMatrix(child.select('lat','lon').rdd.map(lambda row: IndexedRow(row[0], Vectors.dense(row[1:]))))
```

But its throwing me error. I want to avoid converting to pandas dataframe to get the matrix.

error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 33.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 33.0 (TID 733, ebdp-avdc-d281p.sys.comcast.net, executor 16): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/02/yarn/nm/usercache/mbansa001c/appcache/application_1506130884691_56333/container_e48_1506130884691_56333_01_000017/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 174, in main
    process()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to avoid pandas, but you try to convert to an RDD, which is severely suboptimal...

Anyway, assuming you can `collect` the selected columns of your `child` dataframe (a reasonable assumption, since you aim to put them in a Numpy array), it can be done with plain Numpy:

```
import numpy as np
np.array(child.select('lat1', 'lon1').collect())
# array([[80, 70], 
#        [65, 75]])
```